# My radio says ERRE only. How do I get the word CODE to show?

Tags: audio, crv

I need to reset my 2004 Honda radio. I have the code and the serial number. I can't get the screen to show the word CODE. It shows ERRE only and won't change to CODE. What do I do?

Answer (score 1):

ErrE is displayed when the code is entered wrong 10 times or when the radio is faulty.

If it is due to the wrong code then you have to disconnect the battery for over 30seconds although go for 5 minutes to be sure.

Power up the radio and then Code should appear again.

Make sure you are entering the security code and not the serial number